# QProcess не выводит результат выполнения команды

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess

В заголовочном файле прописано

```
const QString windowsCommandProgramm = "tasklist.exe";
const QString windowsCommandArgs = "/fo list";
```

Если выполнять через Win+R получится следующий ответ:

```
Имя образа:     conhost.exe
PID:            11104
Имя сессии:     Console
№ сеанса:       1
Память:         10 908 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   DESKTOP-88NIKGJ\BBCCA
Время ЦП:       0:00:00
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     gdborig.exe
PID:            5476
Имя сессии:     Console
№ сеанса:       1
Память:         70 256 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   DESKTOP-88NIKGJ\BBCCA
Время ЦП:       0:00:01
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     SLauncher.exe
PID:            13228
Имя сессии:     Console
№ сеанса:       1
Память:         1 676 КБ
Состояние:      Running
Пользователь:   DESKTOP-88NIKGJ\BBCCA
Время ЦП:       0:00:57
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     msedge.exe
PID:            9992
Имя сессии:     Console
№ сеанса:       1
Память:         106 812 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   DESKTOP-88NIKGJ\BBCCA
Время ЦП:       0:00:14
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     msedge.exe
PID:            13704
Имя сессии:     Console
№ сеанса:       1
Память:         87 364 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   DESKTOP-88NIKGJ\BBCCA
Время ЦП:       0:00:02
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     svchost.exe
PID:            4768
Имя сессии:     Services
№ сеанса:       0
Память:         7 524 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА
Время ЦП:       0:00:00
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     tasklist.exe
PID:            6272
Имя сессии:     Console
№ сеанса:       1
Память:         10 056 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   DESKTOP-88NIKGJ\BBCCA
Время ЦП:       0:00:00
Заголовок окна: Н/Д

Имя образа:     WmiPrvSE.exe
PID:            14144
Имя сессии:     Services
№ сеанса:       0
Память:         9 444 КБ
Состояние:      Unknown
Пользователь:   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Время ЦП:       0:00:00
Заголовок окна: Н/Д
```

Далее я прописал комманду:

```
QProcess process;
process.start(consoleCommandProgramm, QStringList() << consoleCommandArgs);

if( !process.waitForStarted() || !process.waitForFinished() ) {
       return false;
   }

qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(process.readAll().toStdString());
```

В выводе же:

```
17:25:28: Отладка запущена
""
17:31:23: Отладка завершена
```

Почему так происходит?
И как вывести список процессов?

**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
UPD: добавил текущий результат

```
bool checkProcesses(std::vector<std::string>* blackList){

    std::string osName = QSysInfo::productType().toStdString();

    QString consoleCommandProgramm = ((osName == "windows") || (osName == "winrt"))? windowsCommandProgramm : posixCommandProgramm;
    QString consoleCommandArgs = ((osName == "windows") || (osName == "winrt"))? windowsCommandArgs : posixCommandArgs;

    auto process = new QProcess();
    process->start(consoleCommandProgramm, QStringList() << consoleCommandArgs);

    // Qt5+
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&]() {
        qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(process->readAll().toStdString());
    });



    return true;

}
```

Comment: Так нельзя, используйте указатель на QProcess - доберусь до компа обновлю ответ

Comment: Странно, что объект удаляется при выходе из области видимости? Так было всегда :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Сейчас перевел на указатели и та же херь

Comment: 22:05:06: Отладка запущена

Comment: ""     {здесь пусто прост нужен объем для отправки коммента}

Comment: 22:07:21: Отладка завершена

Comment: Т.е. списка процессов все равно не выводит

Comment: Подозреваю дело в /fo list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1:
Процесс сразу возвращает результат и завершает свою работу (код расположен в одном методе):

```
QProcess process;
// Запускаем процесс
process.start("tasklist", QStringList() << "/FO" << "list");

// Ждем завершения его работы
process.waitForFinished();

// Получаем и выводим результат
qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
```

Вариант 2:

Использовать сигнал [QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput), который срабатывает когда имеются данные в стандартном потоке вывода.

Объект процесса должен "жить" до получения результата работы (например, быть полем класса)

```
QProcess process;
process.start(consoleCommandProgramm, QStringList() << "/fo" << "list");

// Qt5+
// Основной вывод
connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&]() {
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(process.readAll().toStdString());
});
// Ошибки
connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [&]() {
    qDebug() << process.readAllStandardError();
});
```

Comment: 20:04:06: Отладка запущена

Comment: QProcess: Destroyed while process ("tasklist.exe") is still running.

Comment: 20:08:14: Отладка завершена

Comment: И все - все равно не выводит список процессов(

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG у вас убивается объект процесса до того, как он завершил свою работу. Где и как вы создаете объект process?

Comment: Вот полный код функции (Добавил в вопрос выше)

Comment: const QString windowsCommandProgramm = "tasklist.exe";

Comment: const QString windowsCommandArgs = "/fo list";

Comment: Эти две строки в заголовке

Comment: Подозреваю дело в /fo list

Answer (score 0):

`/fo` и `list` — это два разных аргумента. Соответственно и передавать их надо отдельно:

```
process.start(consoleCommandProgramm, QStringList() << "/fo" << "list");
```